# Detect Touch Gesture "Button is pressed" in Delphi

Tags: delphi, touch, gesture, touch-event

In my Delphi application I have a **button which runs a motor as long as the button is pressed**.

Using a mouse this works perfectly. ✅

Now I have a **touch display** and the **pressing and holding** of this button via touch is interpreted as right click. So I am not able to run my motor as long as I press this button. ❌

Currently I am using the events `OnMouseDown` to start the movement of the motor and `OnMouseUp` to stop it.

Unfortunately I did not find events like `OnTouchDown` an `OnTouchUp`.

[image]

Is there another possibility to detect these missing(?) events?

Answer (score 0):

By Default `TButton` does not have support for any gestures. So the Right Click that happens when you touch and hold your button is the fallback mechanism from the OS to allow using touch screen with applications that that don't have touch support. This is done by simulating mouse events.

So in order to get proper control to gesture you will have to replace your button with some other control that has touch support.

I have used `TImage` in similar scenarios before. But I bet some 3rd part libraries might even contain custom buttons which do have support for gestures.